# Tesseract OCR using Java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I have tried to implement the tesseract ocr using Java. But I want the output of converted image to be stored in separate text file.
But I am getting empty `test.txt` file.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.*;
    import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import java.io.File;


    public class BasicTesseractExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void givenTessBaseApi_whenImageOcrd_thenTextDisplayed() throws Exception {
        BytePointer outText;

        TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
        // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
        if (api.Init(".", "ENG") != 0) {
            System.err.println("Could not initialize tesseract.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Open input image with leptonica library 
        PIX image = pixRead("IMG_0012 (1).jpg");
        api.SetImage(image);

        // Get OCR result
        outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
        String string = outText.getString();
        assertTrue(!string.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("OCR output:\n" + string);
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        TeePrintStream tee = new TeePrintStream(file, System.out);
        System.setOut(tee);

        // Destroy used object and release memory
        api.End();
        outText.deallocate();
        pixDestroy(image);

    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("OCR output:\n" + string);` shouldn't that not go after `System.setOut(tee);` ? And don't forget to flush/close the stream.

Comment: I do believe @PeterMmm solved the mistery.

Answer (score 0):

Add return type string and in main method write System.out.println(tee);